# how to hide the navigation controller back button and create the left barbutton and rightbarbutton in iOS xamarin monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

i want to hide the navigation back bar button its not working i mentioned my code below :

```
this.NavigationItem.HidesBackButton = true;

    this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(
        new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Save, (sender,args) => 
            {

                Console.WriteLine("clicking save");
                // button was clicked
            } )
        , true);

    this.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel,(sender,EventArgs)=>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("button was clicked");
            this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
        } )
        ,true);
```

this code is not working back button is not hiding.pl anybody suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Why is iOS tag mentioned?

Comment: @Miroslav, look at the code. It's xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Where is this code executing? Try it in the constructor. It looks fine otherwise.